# Rake test with redgreen gem always finish with "0 tests"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redgreen

Just by adding the gem redgreen, the 'rake test' always finish by the line :

*0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors*

I've created a example project on github:
https://github.com/joel1di1/test_colored_tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Gemfile, change the group from being both :development and :test to just :test.

This way the redgreen gem is required in when you are running tests.